# how to retrieve the column which is of datetime in the resultset using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table `exam` which has a column

```
name,id,examstartdate,examenddate
```

Now while retrieving using resultset. I get like

```
rs.getString("name");
rs.getInt("id");
```

Now since `examstartdate` and `examenddate` are in `datetime` datatype

How to retriev it do i have to give

`rs.getString("examstartdate")`

or what has to be given.

Comment: `getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date` which does not contain a time or more precisely - to quote the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) - "*by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero*". Do read the JavaDocs it's all in there. Honestly: why don't you just try?

Comment: i tried and then only asked ok